# Silverstripe "Security" permission

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to allow a group of users to be able to login to the cms and manager members under security e.g. add/edit/delete member.

I created a new group called `CanManageMembers` and gave permission for `Security` section. The users who belong to this group can login and go to security section but all buttons and fields are disabled. So they can't add/edit any member.

Anything less then `Full Administrator` permission give the same result.

Can this be done? Can I have group of people whose only job is to manager members?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have enabled `Access to 'Security' section`, `Apply roles to groups`, and `Manage permissions for groups`?

Actually that should work, or at least it's doing that for me in 2.4.5.